# Windows Explorer Conditional Context Menu Item for Drive?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell

I have a right-click context menu item that shows up for drive letters in Windows Explorer.  I would like to make it conditional by executing a program with the drive letter passed as a parameter that could query if the drive should have the context menu item or not.  The program could return 1 or 0 to indicate if it should show or not.

Is there a way to do that?

TIA!!

Comment: If you're adding the context menus via a shell extension then you get told which object was right-clicked via the `IShellExtInit::Initialize` method, and you can decide then whether to add the menu item or not. If they're static context menus you've added via the registry, then Explorer does support some form of conditional logic (see e.g. the default context menu item for Bitlocker) but I don't believe Microsoft have ever documented it for third-parties to use.

Comment: That is the `AppliesTo` ? using properties won't work, I need to send an IOCTL to the drive to check the driver stack.

Comment: AppliesTo is currently the only supported declarative filtering mechanism.

Comment: I found `C++ Windows Shell context menu handler` (`(CppShellExtContextMenuHandler)`) and it works great!  I presume it's clean/production level.   One thing is since I had the static items that installed itself so the path is known, is there a recommendation on where to store the path of the program to run (or perhaps I'll lookup the innosetup install path) ?

Comment: CppShellExtContextMenuHandler is an (old) official sample from Microsoft https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/OneCodeTeam/C%2B%2B%20Windows%20Shell%20context%20menu%20handler%20(CppShellExtContextMenuHandler) Since it's COM-based, the binary needs to be registered but you can basically install it anywhere you want